# Unexpected behavior of displaying output of ParametricRegion

Tags: bugs, regions, geometry, visualization, parametric-functions

**Bug persisting in 11.3**

---

A 3D disk `Region` placed at `{1,0,0}` visualizes correctly:

```
Region[ParametricRegion[{{1,0,0} + r { Cos[a], Sin[a], 0}, 
   0 <= r <= 1 && 0 <= a <= 2 Pi}, {a, r}]]
```

But when using a `MachinePrecision` number `{1.,0,0}` only half of the disk gets visualized:

```
Region[ParametricRegion[{{1.,0, 0} + r { Cos[a], Sin[a], 0}, 
       0 <= r <= 1 && 0 <= a <= 2 Pi}, {a, r}]]
```

Exchanging the independent variables `{r,a}` corrects the behavior:

```
Region[ParametricRegion[{{1., 0, 0} + r { Cos[a], Sin[a], 0}, 
   0 <= r <= 1 && 0 <= a <= 2 Pi}, {r, a}]]
```

Need the independent variables be ordered in a specific way? If so why?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in the visualization code in `Region`, but all the properties of the `ParametricRegion` itself are OK.  For example, if you compute the `Area` of the two regions, both will give `3.14...`.   If you haven't already done so, please report this as a bug in `Region` to support.